# Child fragment's options menu not removed from activity's action bar after parent fragment detached

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using the `appcompat-v7:24.2.1` support library. I have an fragment(parent fragment) which has child fragments, one of the child fragment has options menu. When I add the parent fragment to an activity, the child fragment's options menu appears in the activity's action bar, that's ok. But when I remove the parent fragment from the activity, the options menu provided by the child fragment is still on the activity's action bar, The `onDestoryOptionsMenu()` callback is never called on the child fragment. Does anyone has the same problem? How do I walk around this?

Comment: `24.2.1` is literally years out of date. Have you tried with a recent version of the Support Library?